# cant get list of objects using lambda with condition

Tags: c#

I have an Entity in the db :

```
public double? CompletedAtRate { get; set; } = default!;
public string? NettingStatus { get; set; } = default!;

public ICollection<ConvertedQidEntity> IncludedQids { get; set; } = default!;

public DateTime LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

public bool IsTransfered { get; set; }

public string TransactionEntityGuid { get; set; } = default!;
public int ConversionID { get; set; } = default!;
```

I'm trying to run the following query but I get an error saying `Int` does not contain definition for `transactionEntityGUID`. I want to get the list of all `ConvesitionIds`:

```
var listOfInvolvedConversions = db.ConversionEntities
    .Select(f => f.ConversionID)
    .Where(s => s.TransactionEntityGuid = transferGuid)
    .ToList();
```

`transferGuid` is an incoming parameter which is  a string

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should that be equality operator rather than assignment? `.Where(s => s.TransactionEntityGuid == transferGuid)`

Comment: Also swap `Select` and `Where`.

Comment: After `.Select(f => f.ConversionID)` the enumeration contains only this id as an `int`. Therefore, you are not able to select `TransactionEntityGuid`. As @AlexanderPetrov says, swap `Select` and `Where`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yes great help thanks and mulkrj thanks for the hint its working

Answer (score 0):

According to @mulkraj: replace the assigment operator `=` by the equality operator `==`.

According to @AlexanderPetrov: Swap `Select` and `Where`.

```cs
var listOfInvolvedConversionIds = db.ConversionEntities
    .Where(s => s.TransactionEntityGuid == transferGuid)
    .Select(f => f.ConversionID)
    .ToList();
```